# Would such a question be kosher or should it be flagged?

Tags: support, flagging

Here's a hypothetical situation.  Suppose someone asks a question requesting traditional regional synonyms for *gay/homosexual,* many of which are hurtful, and there's no discernible intellectual reason for requesting the information.  **Would that be considered flaggable?  If so, what would be the right category?**  On the one hand, [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor) doesn't appear to have anything that would justify such a flag.  On the other hand, the [Be Nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) page seems to support such a flag, with the following as an example of material to be flagged:

> Bigotry of any kind. Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/offensive-language/info and https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/pejorative-language/info I think they answer this question, at least partially.

Comment: @NVZ - Thanks, but that doesn't help.  Please imagine a very different type of question, with no discernible redeeming value.  Here, I'll make something up.  Question: Please provide regional synonyms for *cunt* that will have a similar tone but specific to such-and-so region.
 (Please excuse the vulgarity but I wanted to give a clear example of something vulgar and pejorative.)

Comment: See also: [Can anything be done about mean-spirited requests for terminology?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4842/50044)

Comment: I am not writing an answer, so I'm merely supplying useful resources for whoever wishes to write one: Here's a relevant bit from an SE employee on another meta: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2220/345

Comment: +1 How is this not a useful question, downvoter?

Comment: @MetaEd Beats me. I wish people would indicate their disagreement with a meta question with an answer/comment rather than merely downvoting the question. Meta questions are what keeps the site functioning well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you think it is gratuitously vulgar, why wouldn’t you flag it as rude/abusive? That the community might not agree shouldn’t change your judgement of what is best for the site, and trolling or otherwise disrupting the community is something I think falls under the "abusive" flag.

If you think someone isn’t asking in good faith, you could also ask your mod team to take a look. Sometimes mods have information that makes it easier to decide if a question is trolling or genuine. They can also edit a question to make it more likely to inspire English-related answers (and make that edit stick if necessary).

Whether a particular question is the sort of thing the community wants to entertain is up to the community. Your responsibility as a community member is simply to "speak up" when you feel something doesn't belong on the site and be respectful of the folks that disagree with you so there can be a constructive discussion. If you feel very strongly about a specific question, flagging might not be enough. You may need to bring it up on meta and explain why you really don't want that question on EL&U.

Comment: +1 This gets to the heart of the issue. A troll can very well be *technically* on topic for the site. It's still a troll.

Comment: +1 And here's something possibly relevant: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2314/345

Comment: I was asking about something that actually happened (but not at ELU); the OP was not a troll but I found the question and even more, the answers, offensive.  This answer is very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @NVZ - Interesting reading -- although not relevant in this particular case.  Still, it's good to know for future reference to prevent problems from snowballing.