# Is this question, asking for an insulting term, clear enough to provide a good answer as opposed to a laundry list?

Tags: discussion

I refer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/488793/insult-for-someone-who-doesnt-know-anything): Insult for someone who “doesn't know anything”?

I VTC'd on the basis of Unclear What You are Asking, because I didn't find any context.  Is the person to be insulted lazy, or dyslexic, or all thumbs with anything mechanical but a genius in the most abstruse mathematics, or disabled, or a dreamer?  Is this for a story the OP is writing? the OP says

> someone who doesn't know anything (meaning not the simplest/basic or
>   obvious things)?

but I doubt that he has tested this person in all fields of human knowledge.

I feel uncomfortable with this question, partly because it is a flawed question, but mainly because it could be a mean question, although that is not clear.

There is a [five-year-old question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4842/can-anything-be-done-about-mean-spirited-requests-for-terminology) about how we should deal with questions asking how to insult people, which did not come to much of a conclusion.

**But, what we can do is VTC such a question that is flawed for standard reasons.**

I have recast my question so it is not a duplicate of the earlier question.

Comment: The post that ab2 asks about specifically frames the SWR as a request for an insult term. In such a case, I don't see how tagging it as pejorative-language is inaccurate or unfair to the poster. As tchrist wrote in his Meta question about mean-spirited requests for terminology, "[Q]uestions asking about insults or slurs are questions that deserve to be labelled pejorative. It bothered me how many of these there were, and how they tend to draw bikeshedding list responses with no right answer. It doesn’t look good." I agree.

Comment: I voted to close this as primarily opinion based. I find that insults are particularly subjective, so there can't be a clear *winner* in this case. (As it turns out, my vote was the one that tipped it over and closed it out.) As for the other point, there is nothing wrong with this being a *mean* post—and tagging it with `pejorative-language` seems completely reasonable in this case, since it's explicitly asking for insulting words. Anybody can downvote it if they don't like it, but I don't think it should be *closed* on that specific basis (not that there is such a reason available).