# Are there more requests for disparaging language on the weekends?

Tags: discussion

Is it only me, or has anybody else noticed that many, if not most of the “nasty” and “mean spirited” requests for pejorative language occur on the weekend?

Apart from filtering for “pejorative” tag, how can we correlate with date?

I realize that “nasty” is subjective….but I think we all recognize them. Most of them involve “What is your favorite insult?”

example from a now-deleted comment on a [now-closed question...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494640/im-looking-for-a-less-misognystic-but-equally-insulting-word-as-b)

> "evil is good enough, anyways. i guess this was closed cos i'm in effect asking for your favourite insult haha –

[EDIT] the question has been deleted for "moderation purposes"

SEE: [Can anything be done about mean-spirited requests for terminology?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4842/can-anything-be-done-about-mean-spirited-requests-for-terminology)

Comment: On a typical day there might be up to [fifty questions](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) posted on EL&U. Would you say the number of requests for epithets and its ilk  are roughly one a day? And on a bad day how many would that be? Three or more? Or are you saying that these types of *legitimate* requests (they're not off topic unless the research is lacking)  typically occur once a week? Well, it's not so bad is it? Ignore them. I'm saying that someone who uses the word "bitch" in a legitimate and on-topic  question should not be condemned.

Comment: Where is the evidence that *Most of them involve “What is your favorite insult?”* I don't see that many, in fact I don't really recall anyone asking on the main site what is our favourite insult? And if they did, those types of question are usually closed instantly for being too broad or opinion-based.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm here everyday, and it just seems to me that the preponderance of these types of questions occur on the weekends...I am trying to find a way to prove or disprove that.

Comment: Ask on Meta (MSE)  if there's a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) inquiry for that sort of thing. OMG, I don't believe I actually said that. Wow, I'm getting geeky! P.S Ack, Mitch uses a different term. Didn't know that one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You are probably one of the nicest geeks I know here.

Comment: Shucks, you leave me with no choice but to upvote your question.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com):

> https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/1036937/posts-tagged-pejorative-by-day-of-week#graph

where it shows that the marked max is the middle of the week, Wednesday.

If you remove the 'where' clause, you'll get *all* posts, and you'll see that it *also* has its max on Wednesday.

It could be a psychological thing, where on the weekends where there are fewer posts altogether, the few pejorative ones might just stand out.

Comment: I think that moderation is also less on the weekend, which leads to fewer questions being downvoted and closed (and enough downvotes remove a question from the Home page).

Comment: Do they also have sloppy English and typos?  Maybe the OPs are drunk.

Comment: Worth noting that the chart's week begins with a Sunday and not a Monday in order to see that 4 is equivalent to a Wednesday. In my dialect, Wednesday is the third day of the week and Sunday is the end of the weekend.

Comment: If I did the math right, expressed as a percentage of the whole, your query shows that "pejorative-language" questions *are*, over all dates, most common on Sunday (0.3278177), second most common on Wednesday (0.296077), followed by Friday (0.2690417) and Saturday (0.268695). That says nothing about recent trends.

Comment: @JEL I'm not sure what math you're doing. In the graph, 1=Sun:84, 2=Mon:80, 3=Tue:83, 4=Wed:104, 5=Thu:86, 6=Fri:87, 7=Sun:65. Wed is the max by far, Sat the min by far, Sun and Fri both middling.

Comment: Not to make heavy weather of it, because the stats pertain to the total of all questions asked, ever, on a given weekday, and so don't show much about recent use (e.g., question totals per weekday since Cascabel started looking), but the perceived frequency is a percentage of the total questions asked on any given day of the week. So, the total of pejorative questions shown in the graph you created, divided by the total of all questions asked on that day of the week (and multiplied times 100). Even so, I haven't bothered to look at boundary conditions: ...

Comment: a total of 104 pejorative questions on Wednesday for the entire history of ELU seems rather low, but I suppose it could be right. So (104/35126)*100 is the math for the history of Wednesday on ELU.

Comment: @JEL it may be heavy weather but those are good suggestions in refining the answer. Instead of eyeballing with comparison to all questions, I should give a graph of the fraction. Also probably limit to 'recently'... sometime later today...

Comment: @JEL For the record...I started noticing this "trend" around the time that I first started working in the VTC queues, i.e. 2 years ago. This "observation" is probably only anecdotal, but I have very retentive memory. Also there is the other issue of "mean-spirited", and how to judge such a thing.